# Change space from fread txt file

Tags: php

Good day. I'm trying to read the `txt` file. So here is what inside my `txt`

```
SS,SS,SS,BSM160801870,1
SS,SS,SS,BSM160801825,1
SS,SS,SS,BSM160801812,1
SS,SS,SS,BSM160701676,1
SS,SS,SS,BSM160501311,1
SS,SS,SS,BSM160501351,1
SS,SS,SS,BSM160701721,1
SS,SS,SS,BSM160501269,1
```

so i read the file using this

```
$myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$textfile = fread($myfile,filesize($file));
echo $textfile;
```

But the result is like this

```
SS,SS,SS,BSM160801870,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160801825,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160801812,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160701676,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160501311,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160501351,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160701721,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160501269,1
```

so i want to give `;` in every `space` at the result so i try to using this

```
$myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$textfile = fread($myfile,filesize($file));
$textfiles = str_replace(" ",";",$textfile);
echo $textfiles;
```

but no help.

my desired result is like this

```
SS,SS,SS,BSM160801870,1;SS,SS,SS,BSM160801825,1;SS,SS,SS,BSM160801812,1;SS,SS,SS,BSM160701676,1;SS,SS,SS,BSM160501311,1;SS,SS,SS,BSM160501351,1;SS,SS,SS,BSM160701721,1;SS,SS,SS,BSM160501269,1
```

how can i achieve that ? thanks in advance.

working fine if i do this

```
$string = "SS,SS,SS,BSM160801870,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160801825,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160801812,1 SS,SS,SS,BSM160701676";  
        $textfiles = str_replace(" ",";",$string);
        echo $textfiles;
```

Comment: your `str_replace` soln worked for me. `echo $textfiles;` should be same as the desired result shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While echoing file content all your new line will be converted to simple space.

You need to replace `\r\n` to `;` `preg_replace('/\r\n/', ';', file_get_contents($myfile))`

Comment: If the file was not created using windows you will probably have to change `\r\n` to `\n`

Comment: @rypskar Yes, or one dirty way is just replace `\n` leaving `\r`.